# Trigger.. AFTER and BEFORE with specific column changed

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-8.4

I'm a postgresql user and I'm trying to follow this :
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (OLD.balance IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.balance) 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_account_update();
```

but with AFTER instead of BEFORE. and I'm keep getting error on or near WHEN. 
does that because i have to use BEFORE ? what if i need to execute the procedure after updating column and it has really changed ?

Comment: What error are you getting and what does your `create trigger` look like?

Comment: And which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: i get:

Syntax error at or near 'WHEN' 
LINE 1: ... check_update AFTER UPDATE ON accounts FOR EACH ROW WHEN (OLD.balance IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.balance) ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.4 doesn't support WHEN with triggers, from the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html):

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER name { BEFORE | AFTER } { event [ OR ... ] }
> ON table [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
> EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcname ( arguments )
> ```

There is no WHEN there. You can put the WHEN logic inside your trigger function:

```
if old.balance is not distinct from new.balance then
    return new;
end if;
-- The rest of the trigger...
```

or upgrade to at least [PostgreSQL 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtrigger.html) and use WHEN when creating the trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much! appreciate your help